# Передача вектора в функцию по ссылке

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.
Как решить эту ошибку?!

Ошибка:

```
In member function ‘void Blocks::SetCube(std::vector<Texture2f>*, std::vector<Vector3f>*, std::vector<unsigned int>*, char)’:
/home/hays/program/WorldMap/Blocks.cpp:112:55: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<Texture2f>’
                 TextureBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u;
                                                       ^
/home/hays/program/WorldMap/Blocks.cpp:113:55: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<Texture2f>’
                 TextureBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->v = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].v;
                                                       ^
/home/hays/program/WorldMap/Blocks.cpp:119:54: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<Vector3f>’
                 VertexBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->x = CubeGrass.VertexData[i].x;
                                                      ^
/home/hays/program/WorldMap/Blocks.cpp:120:54: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<Vector3f>’
                 VertexBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->y = CubeGrass.VertexData[i].y;
                                                      ^
/home/hays/program/WorldMap/Blocks.cpp:121:54: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<Vector3f>’
                 VertexBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->z = CubeGrass.VertexData[i].z;
                                                      ^
/home/hays/program/WorldMap/Blocks.cpp:128:50: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’ and ‘unsigned int’)[/COLOR]
             IndexBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1] = CubeGrass.IndexData[i];
```

Структуры:

```
typedef float Scalar;

struct Vector3f
{
    Scalar x, y, z;
};

struct Texture2f
{
    Scalar u, v;
};
```

Функция:

```
using namespace std;

void Blocks::SetCube(vector <Texture2f> *TextureBuffer,vector <Vector3f> *VertexBuffer,
vector <GLuint> *IndexBuffer,char type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case 0:

            for(int i(0);i<24;i++)
            {
                TextureBuffer->push_back(Texture2f());
                TextureBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u;
                TextureBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->v = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].v;
            }

            for( int i(0);i<24;i++)
            {
                VertexBuffer->push_back(Vector3f());
                VertexBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->x = CubeGrass.VertexData[i].x;
                VertexBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->y = CubeGrass.VertexData[i].y;
                VertexBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->z = CubeGrass.VertexData[i].z;

            }

            for(int i(0);i<36;i++)
            {
            IndexBuffer->push_back(GLuint());
            IndexBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1] = CubeGrass.IndexData[i];
            } 

            break; 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Извлекаемое из вектора значение является не указателем, а ссылкой. Вместо

```
TextureBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u;
```

следует писать

```
TextureBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1].u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u;
```

А вообще, вместо того, чтобы добавлять элемент, а потом для каждого изменения его поля заново получать его из вектора, лучше бы сначала задали значения полей, а потом добавляли:

```
Texture2f tex;
tex.u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u;
tex.v = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].v;
TextureBuffer->push_back(text);
```

Ну и можно передавать векторы не по указателю, а по ссылке:

```
void Blocks::SetCube(
    vector<Texture2f>& TextureBuffer,
    vector<Vector3f>& VertexBuffer,
    vector<GLuint>& IndexBuffer,
    char type)
```

Тогда можно вместо `->` использовать `.`:

```
Texture2f tex;
tex.u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u;
tex.v = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].v;
TextureBuffer.push_back(text);
```

По-моему, эстетичнее.

Comment: Побывал с TextureBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1].u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u; ошибка типа
/home/hays/program/WorldMap/Blocks.cpp:112:56: error: ‘class std::vector<Texture2f>’ has no member named ‘u’
                 TextureBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1].u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u;
                                                        ^
/home/hays/program/WorldMap/Blocks.cpp:113:56: error: ‘class std::vector<Texture2f>’ has no member named ‘v’
                 TextureBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1].v = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].v;

Comment: @hays Добавьте текст ошибок в вопрос в отформатированном виде. Заодно убедитесь, что в классе действительно есть такое поле. Ну и обновите код в соответствии хотя бы с первым советом из ответа (после "а потом добавляли") — ошибку будет лучше видно.

Answer (score 3):

Зачем Вы передаёте указатель на вектор в функцию? Передавайте ссылку и проблем с синтаксисом не будет. А сейчас Вы делаете не верно:

```
TextureBuffer[TextureBuffer->size()-1]->u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u;
```

Означает буквально следующее: `(TextureBuffer + TextureBuffer->size() - 1)->u` - это undefined behavior(неопределённое поведение), т.к. Вы полезли в память, которая непонятно где.
Правильно будет писать так:

```
*(TextureBuffer)[TextureBuffer->size()-1].u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u;
```

или так:

```
TextureBuffer->back().u = CubeGrass.TextureData[i].u;
```